# Class ::CakeTime in Model cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

i'm trying to access the class CakeTime in my Model and CakePHP doesn't seem to recognize it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'CakeTime', 'Utility');

class Rex extends AppModel {

public function month_entries($created){

    //création des mois qui vont servir de critère de recherche
    $month=CakeTime::format("$created", '%Y-%m');

    //on récupère le 1er du mois recherché
    $month=$month."-01"; 

    //on se place au premier du mois suivant
    $month_plus_un=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month",strtotime($month))); 

    $count = $this->Article->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Rex.date_incident >='=> $month,
            'Rex.date_incident <'=> $month_plus_un )));

    return $count;

}
```

I get an error as soon as i call CakeTime.

am i missing something in syntax ? The documentation is unclear on how to call core library utilities in Model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `App::uses(...)` declaration is wrong, it shoulld be:
`App::uses(string $class, string $package)` , so, change:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'CakeTime', 'Utility');
```

to

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');
```

Comment: and that's why i love internet and stackOverflow !
btw: do you know how i call a find('count') directly from the model ?

Comment: Perfect ! I was trying $this->Model->find :)